# powershell export group membership multiple job titles

Tags: powershell

I have a csv with below eachother multiple job titles so like this:

```
Job title 1
Job title 2
Job title 3
```

What I now need is to export the group memberships of the user that has that job title so for example a person with job title 1 has a couple of group memberships. I need those group memberships  in a csv. Is it possible to do this automaticly for my whole csv that it does all the job title one by one?

I have this:

`Get-ADUser -Filter {title -Like "Medior Functioneel beheerder"} | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | select name`

How do I get it so it only does this for one match since we have multiple users with the same job title but I only need it for one user. And how do I export this to an csv preferably on one line. for each job title.

Comment: Do you need a csv with one row per person with one of the job titles? Or each row just a job title with a list of all distinct group names that people with that job title has?

Comment: I have one row for each job title so so each row just the job title with all the assosiated groups that it gets from a user.

Comment: That's definitely doable. Have you tried... anything? :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I currently have this : 
`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Filter {title -Like "Medior Functioneel beheerder"} -Properties
Title | Select Title` But that doesnt work since get adprincialgroupmembership doesnt have a filter option

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach it like this:

- For each job title:

  - Retrieve all users with their `memberOf` values
  - Select all distinct memberships
  - Output a custom object with title + list of memberships
- Export custom objects to CSV

```bsh
$csv = @'
Title
Job title 1
Job title 2
Job title 3
'@ |ConvertFrom-Csv # you'd use `Import-Csv` here instead

$result = foreach($row in $csv){
  # Fetch all relevant users with their `memberOf` attribute value
  $Users = Get-ADUser -Filter "title -eq '$($row.Title)'" -Properties memberOf

  # Select all distinct memberOf values
  $Memberships = $Users.memberOf |Sort -Unique

  # Resolve the group names
  $GroupNames = ($Memberships |Get-ADGroup).Name

  # Output custom object 
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Title = $row.Title
    Groups = $GroupNames -join ';'
  } 
}

# output to CSV
$result |Export-Csv -Path .\output.csv
```